# Community Search in an undirected graph using networkx?

Tags: python, networking, graph, networkx, infrastructure

I'd like to discover communities within networks using networkx. The network I am studying is the [cat brain](https://neurodata.io/project/connectomes/), downloadable as a .EDGES file. It is an undirected graph. I read it in like so:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cat_brain = ".//data//cat_brain.graphml"
cat = nx.read_graphml(cat_brain)

plt.title("Cat brain")
nx.draw(cat,pos=nx.spring_layout(cat),node_size=25, width=0.1) # use spring layout
```

I would like to use networkx to describe this community in more detail. Perhaps even assess its resilience and connectivity. However, I've had trouble finding much info on this process. What I've done so far is:

```
from networkx.algorithms.approximation import clique
from networkx.algorithms.community import k_clique_communities

print("Cat brain basic graph info:",nx.info(cat))
print("max clique of cat",clique.max_clique(cat))
```

I would like to run similarity analyses and search for communities within the network. Thereafter, I would run a divisive algorithm to isolate communities, and eventually be able to plot the network, reworked in color to show multiple communities. But, the [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.community.html) of networkx community algorithms is limited to just one algorithm. Are there tools within networkx to do this work? Should I look elsewhere to another python package?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of communities you're looking for? There are at least a dozen of popular community detection algorithms out there. As an alternative to `networkx`, I would recommend `networkit`. It implementes many community detection  algorithms but is somewhat sparse on documentation.

Comment: My goal is to use similarity analysis, like an agglomerate algorithm, to merge nodes with high similarity into communities. Thereafter, I will use a divisive algorithm to isolate communities. Such algorithms may be the ravasz and girvan-newman algorithms. All of this is based on one lecture on network analysis, out of 13 lectures on infrastructure so my knowledge is low. I have 3 brain networks, and I essentially want to look for differences between them. Feeling kind of lost, even after chatting with the professor.

Comment: @Marat Is it possible to test the connectivity of these graphs using networkx or networkit tools?

Comment: Well, research is always tricky. There are many measures of similarity and many community detection algorithms. Depending on how they were operationalized, the results will be different  and at some point you'll need to explain the choice of features, similarity metrics and algorithms. Unfortunately, nobody can answer these questions for you, and one lecture is in no way enough to make these choices in an informed manner

Comment: @Marat Precisely. It's a 1 credit course... Meh, well I'll do my best. Thanks for your input. I have found a number of useful algorithms just by reading the references for networkx. This document was published today. Big coincidence! Super helpful. https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/_downloads/networkx_reference.pdf#page=173&zoom=100,96,96